# How exactly does 'Inside Job' work?

Tags: android-netrunner

When a runner uses [Inside Job](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=inside%20job), does the runner only bypass the first 'rezzed' piece of ice, since the card text says 'bypass the first piece of ice *encountered* during the run.' ? ( emphasis added)

If yes, does that mean if the corp. does not rez any ice, 'Inside Job' has no effect?

Comment: If the corp doesn't rez ice it has an effect, the effect being it discouraged rezzing the ice. Often I see inside job played against a single ice server, the corp doesn't bother to spend and rez, since they have to pay but get no benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summary: Inside Job bypasses the first piece of face up ice on a server, regardless of when that was rezzed.

Note: there are some effects that can cause to to encounter ice that hasn't been installed, such as [Archangel](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09013), or that is installed on [Awakening Center](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03021).  These can also be bypassed with Inside Job if the server has no rezzed ice in front of it.

---

The specific rule for encountering ice is:

> If the approached piece of ice is rezzed after the Corporation has the
>   opportunity to rez cards, then the Runner encounters it.

The confusion here probably comes from the fact that "rezzed" is both an adjective and a verb, depending on context.  In this particular piece of rules, we are dealing with the adjectival form.  Let me translate:

> If the approached piece of ice is [**face up**] after the Corporation has the
>   opportunity to [**turn cards face up**], then the Runner encounters it.

If the ice is face up, it is encountered.  This includes ice that has been turned face up on previous runs/turns.  The reason for the extra bits of the sentence is to clarify that even if the ice was rezzed **just now**, it is still encountered (see the run structure chart at the end of the rulebook).

If you want to stop Inside Job, try effects that prevent bypassing, like the ability on Guard.

Comment: I really like your answer for the quotes and thoroughness, but I think it could benefit from a summary, like:
bypass typically only applies to rezzed ice because typically only rezzed ice are encountered.

Comment: @AndrewVandever i added a summary.  Is there ever a situation where unrezzed ice is encountered?

Comment: Actually you could probably leave out "typically" until some card breaks the statement. :) I had to double-check whether one already does.

Comment: More information: Does this mean if the corporation does not rez any ICE, inside job is not effective, because there is no ICE to 'encounter'?

Comment: @TheDarkLord If the runner encounters no ice then Inside Job does nothing.  However, this only happens if the cop has no face up ice on the server AND turns no ice face up during the run.  Basically, inside job only does nothing if the sever is unprotected and the runner just gets in anyways.  This really only matters if you have only one piece of ice on the server and it's still unrezzed, in which case don't bother rezzing it if the runner is using Inside Job.

Comment: there are some ICE and Awakening Center, that forces the runner to encounter a ICE wich was never rezzed :D

Comment: @diego.martinez actually, Awakening Center rezzes the ice before it forces the encounter

Comment: There are now ice that do fit Diego's comment, Archangel and Sapper for instance.

Comment: @Zags I'd argue Inside Job only does nothing if there is no ice, or the corp can't afford to use the ice. Inside Job, at that point changes the cost/benefit of rezzing ice. Since the first ice the corp rezzes will be bypassed it can ruin anything positional, or make it not worth the credits to rez ice.